# pkg-config fails to find package under sysroot directory

Tags: cross-compiling, spidermonkey, pkg-config

Can anyone please tell me why this might fail:

```
afeder@ubuntu:~/android/toolchain/sysroot$ ls $PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/mozjs185.pc
/home/afeder/android/toolchain/sysroot/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/mozjs185.pc

afeder@ubuntu:~/android/toolchain/sysroot$ pkg-config mozjs185 --cflags
Package mozjs185 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mozjs185.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mozjs185' found
```

According to man [`pkg-config(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config), `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` is supposed to be one of the default search paths.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/pkgconfig/cross-compiling.html

> The wrapper script should not only set the `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR`
>   variable: when cross-compiling you want to ignore the packages
>   installed in the system, and instead rely only on those installed in
>   the cross-compiled environment. This is achieved by resetting
>   `PKG_CONFIG_DIR` (which lists additional search paths), and at the same
>   time setting `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` to override the default base search
>   paths.

---

The resulting CMake File would be something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/path/to/sysroot")

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_DIR} "")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})
```

Disclaimer: I used the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable which is useful when you want to pass `-sysroot` to `g++`. If you don't want this you should name your variable differently.

Comment: Hi, could you possibly show the command you issued to get this working, thanks

Comment: Per https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config, I think you mean `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` instead of `PKG_CONFIG_DIR`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a cross-compiler, then you need to 1) install the appropriate pkg-config wrapper and 2) set the appropriate environment variables to be picked up by the wrapper. You can find the appropriate wrapper with `apt-cache search pkg-config-` and then install the appropriate one for the target system. E.g. if cross-compiling to armhf: `sudo apt-get install pkg-config-arm-linux-gnueabihf`. Then, set environment variables `PKG_CONFIG_DIR`, `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR`, and `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` as required before invoking the wrapper.

If you're cross compiling using CMake, note that CMake's `pkg_search_module` command (provided by `FindPkgConfig.cmake`) doesn't appear to correctly set the environment for the wrapper. Rather, you should use the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

```
# Set these in your toolchain.cmake file
set(triple arm-linux-gnueabihf)
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE ${triple}-pkg-config)
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/${triple}/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig")
```

See also [set PKG_CONFIG_PATH in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487053/set-pkg-config-path-in-cmake)