# set PKG_CONFIG_PATH in cmake

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

I have built opencv locally and installed it to a local directory (not the system default ). `opencv.pc` is present under a folder pkgconfig in this local folder. How can I find this `opencv.pc` from cmake, because I want to link and include opencv files from my program.

```
pkg_search_module(<PREFIX> [REQUIRED] [QUIET] <MODULE> [<MODULE>]*)
```

does not have any parameter in which I can force the command to use a specific path (similar to HINTS with `find_package()`) and not the system default.

So basically `.cmake` works:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED HINTS "my/path/to/share/OpenCVConfig.cmake")
```

but I would like to use a `opencv.pc` located under `my/path/to/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After doing some research and a hint from the @OlivierM, I found the answer.

Here are the steps:

**Method I** :

`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` can be set to find the `.pc` files

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/opencv-install")
```

**Method II** 
A second method is to use the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, which is a system environment variable to look for `.pc` files.

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/opencv-install/lib/pkgconfig")
```

Irrespective of which method you use,

**For old (traditional) CMake:**

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(PKG_OPENCV REQUIRED opencv)  # this looks for opencv.pc file
```

Please note that the `PKG_OPENCV` variable can be named anything. Whatever it is is named, its used as a prefix. For example if you name `ABCD`, then include directories will be `ABCD_INCLUDE_DIRS`

The variable `PKG_OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `PKG_OPENCV_LIBRARIES` contains the header files (compile stage) and libraries (link stage) respectively.

One very important thing I noticed was that the variable `PKG_OPENCV_LIBRARIES` just provides the libraries and not the library path during the link stage. In order to use the library path as well in one command, one has to use

```
PKG_OPENCV_LDFLAGS
```

This variable contains the library path as well as all the libraries listed in the package config file.

for examaple:

```
include_directories(${PKG_OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries (FINAL_BINARY ${PKG_OPENCV_LDFLAGS})
```

**For modern CMake:**

In modern CMake we don't want variables, we want targets.

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
# this looks for opencv.pc file and creates a new target
# IMPORTED_TARGET requires CMake >= 3.6.3
pkg_search_module(PKG_OPENCV REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET opencv)
```

All variables will still be created for backwards compatibility, but `IMPORTED_TARGET` will create a target you can use in your project which will automatically propagate all of its build and usage requirements:

```
target_link_libraries(my_proj PRIVATE PkgConfig::PKG_OPENCV)
```

Comment: I don't know why it isn't using those variables to search...
` CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH, and CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH`

Comment: @DawidDrozd I dont understand your query / statement. Can you plz elaborate?

Comment: I set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` etc and pkg_search_module do not check those paths

Comment: @DawidDrozd then try the envirionment variable. This will definetly find your .pc file. Please note that the first parameter n pkg_search_module can be any thing. I set it to PKG_OPENCV. You can set to ABCD for ex. Also, check with your command line first before going for CMake.. pkg-config --cflags yourpackageconfigfilename.

Comment: don't you mean target_include_directories? Also, can you please add the version of cmake you're talking about in your answer.

Comment: the different is just the scope of include_directories..you can use either of them.  I tested with 2.6. But in the meanwhile I am using 3.8.2. What problems are you facing?

Comment: Method 1 is wrong.  It is a pre-fix path so it would be something like `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /path/to/opencv/install/")`.  Then FindPkgConfig.cmake appends to this as appropriate.

Comment: Yes as @Fred comment, in Method 1 CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH should be set on folder which has share/pkgconfig inside eg. when some custom build is used  by ./configure --prefix=SOME_FOLDER when pc files are generated in SOME_FOLDER/share/pkgconfig.

Comment: On Windows under Cygwin the Method 1 (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH, CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH) does not work now, see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21775.
Another reason why Method 1 may not work for someone is wrong usage: PKG_CONFIG_PATH should include the prefix /lib/pkgconfig, while CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH should not (because FindPkgConfig.cmake appends it automatically).

Answer (score 10):

You could set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with the CMake line:

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/my/path/to/pkgconfig")
```

I did this workaround in this [file](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/CrossCompilation.cmake#L66)

Interestingly, it seems CMake 3.1 extends `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with some CMake variable see: https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=3df51470

Comment: I dont see any pkg_search_module in your code. how are you looking for the modules?

Comment: It is actually a common file I created to support cross-compilation. I used `find_package` in the top `CMakeLists.txt`. See [here](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L30)

Comment: Should there be a directory called `pkgconfig` if you run the command `ls /my/path/to/pkgconfig` or should there just be the `*.pc` file in that location?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose you to call `cmake` with custom `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable, like below:

```bash
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:my/path/to/pkgconfig cmake <some args>
```

Or can make `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` update to be permanent for whole bash session:

```bash
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:my/path/to/pkgconfig
$ cmake <some args>
```