# PKG_CONFIG_PATH A required package was not found

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, libav, libavcodec, pkg-config

I want to link my C++ app with any library, for example with libavcodec.so.
I tried Method I from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489201/7915017

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${pkgconfig_path})
```

But when I try to build

```
cmake -S Qt_FFMpeg/src/ -B Qt_FFMpeg/build-host/ --fresh
```

I get error "A required package was not found".
Ok, I try [Method II](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489201/7915017)

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ${pkgconfig_path})
```

And it works. Why doesn't Method I work?
Full code [here](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/Cpp_libavcodec_Universe.git)

I use Ubuntu 22 x86_64, cmake 3.26.4

Comment: The referenced answer assigns **different values** for `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variables. The variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is assigned with `<...>/opencv-install, the variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is assigned with `<...>/opencv-install/lib/pkgconfig`. In your question post it seems you assign the path `<prefix>/lib/pkgconfig` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, so it doesn't work. Instead you should assign `<prefix>` value to that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now works! Thanks @Tsyvarev

With Environment Variables

```
cmake_path(SET pkgconfig_path "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../FFMpeg_themself/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig/" NORMALIZE)
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ${pkgconfig_path})
message("I found $ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}")
```

Without Environment Variables

```
cmake_path(SET pkgconfig_path "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../FFMpeg_themself/ffmpeg_build/" NORMALIZE)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${pkgconfig_path})
message("I found ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
```