declaring external install of dependencies ZLIB and LIBUV in CMake
The following CMakeLists.txt declares dependencies ZLIB and LIBUV.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyProject VERSION 1.0)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(ZLIB REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET zlib
                        "/home/user/workspace/zlib-1.3.1/lib/pkgconfig/zlib.pc")
pkg_check_modules(LIBUV REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libuv
                        "/home/user/workspace/libuv-1.44.2/lib64/pkgconfig/libuv.pc")

Both libraries have been built in directories /home/user/workspace/zlib-1.3.1 and /home/user/workspace/libuv-1.44.2 with:
$ configure --prefix=${PWD} && make install

Both provide a valid and similar pkgconfig .pc file. That may be checked with:
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/user/workspace/libuv-1.44.2/lib64/pkgconfig pkg-config libuv --modversion
1.44.2
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/user/workspace/zlib-1.3.1/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config zlib --modversion
1.3.1

Still CMake detects zlib but fails to detect libuv:
$ rm -fr CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles/ && cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.27.1")
-- Checking for modules 'zlib;/home/user/workspace/zlib-1.3.1/lib/pkgconfig/zlib.pc'
--   Found zlib, version 1.2.7
--   Found /home/user/workspace/zlib-1.3.1/lib/pkgconfig/zlib.pc, version 1.3.1
-- Checking for modules 'libuv;/home/user/workspace/libuv-1.44.2/lib64/pkgconfig/libuv.pc'
--   No package 'libuv' found
CMake Error at /opt/cmake/cmake-3.19.2/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:553 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake/cmake-3.19.2/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:741 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/workspace/test/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".


Command pkg_check_modules doesn't accept path to the .pc file, like you are tried to use. You need to specify search paths via PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, which is used by pkg-config utility, or via CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH CMake or environment variable, according to which CMake adds corresponding directories to PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Correct: method II of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489201/400925 fixed the problem.
