# How to get CMake find_package to find and use PkgConfig for cross-compilation

Tags: gcc, cmake, cross-compiling, pkg-config

I am trying to cross-compile an application for a Beaglebone black.

I've successfully compiled the application directly on the Beaglebone while commenting out the cross-compile related section in my CMakeLists.txt below.  I've also cross-compiled the `hello` program found in this tutorial: https://github.com/robamu-org/beaglebone-crosscompiling/tree/main

So my goal is to combine the cross-compiling approach from the tutorial, along with the insights from here: [pkg-config fails to find package under sysroot directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221236/pkg-config-fails-to-find-package-under-sysroot-directory)

In order to get CMake to cross-compile correctly with pkg-config and GTKMM.

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

#  ~~~~~~~~~~~ CROSS COMPILE SECTION (commented out on successful beaglebone build)~~~~

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "BBBToolchain.cmake")

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/home/cole/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_DIR} "/home/cole/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs/usr/bin")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})

# ~~~~ CROSS COMPILE SECTION END

project(question-manager CXX)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)

add_executable(EMBEDDED-GUI src/view/embedded-app/opengtk-version/start-gui.cpp
                            src/view/embedded-app/opengtk-version/main-window.cpp
                            src/view/embedded-app/opengtk-version/question-card.cpp)

target_link_libraries(EMBEDDED-GUI PUBLIC ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(EMBEDDED-GUI PUBLIC ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_directories(EMBEDDED-GUI PUBLIC ${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_compile_options(EMBEDDED-GUI PUBLIC ${GTKMM_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

However, when I try to configure CMake, it still uses the Host PkgConfig  (my Host version is "0.29.2" while the targets version is "0.29"

```bash
$ cmake ..
-- Beagle Bone Black sysroot: /home/scshafe/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs
-- No CROSS_COMPILE environmental variable set, using default ARM linux cross compiler name arm-linux-gnueabihf
-- Using sysroot path: /home/scshafe/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs
-- Beagle Bone Black sysroot: /home/scshafe/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs
-- No CROSS_COMPILE environmental variable set, using default ARM linux cross compiler name arm-linux-gnueabihf
-- Using sysroot path: /home/scshafe/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/scshafe/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'gtkmm-3.0'
--   No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:603 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:825 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/scshafe/git-projects/question-list-manager/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

If I add

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/home/scshafe/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig")
```

PkgConfig will find gtkmm-3.0, but it is still using the the "0.29.2" Host version, and ultimately I get linkage errors when trying to build.

Comment: The pkgconfig binary will always need to be the host version, after all it'll have to run on the host machine to find the packages before building it.

Comment: I see, thanks! @Corristo so do you have insight into why the linkage errors occur when PKG_CONFIG_PATH helps pkgconfig find the correct gtkm-3.0.pc file?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Can you maybe post the failing linker call as well as the content of the gtkmm .pc file. My best guess is that using both CMAKE_SYSROOT and PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR causing the linker to search for the library in `/home/cole/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs//home/cole/beaglebone/cross-compiler-toolchain/linaro-toolchain/rootfs/usr/lib`. If that is the case I'd remove the `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` env variable.